# How to set TextFormattingMode programmatically?

Tags: wpf

How can I set the `TextFormattingMode` property programmatically to the MainWindow class?

```
<Window x:Class="EditorExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"            
        TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
</Window>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you want to set from `ManiWindow` class. `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode` is an attached property.

```
this.SetValue(TextOptions.TextFormattingModeProperty, TextFormattingMode.Display);
```

Answer (score 2):

You add the property using the below code.

```
TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(this, TextFormattingMode.Display);
```